# UNIQUE constraint failed: music_playlist.owner_id

Tags: python, django, view

Users can register and login to my website. Users those who are currently logged in to my website could create their own playlist. But when the create button is submitted, it returned me this error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: music_playlist.owner_id

Here is my models.py :

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False,default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def playlist_id(self):
        return self.id
```

This is my views.py(where the error occurs):

```
@login_required
def create_playlist(request):
    form = PlaylistForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data

        playlist = form.save(commit=False)
        playlist.owner = request.user

        playlist.save()
        #playlist_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        context={
            'playlist':playlist,

            'form':form,
        }

        return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', context)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', {'form': form,})
```

When the user goes to create_playlist.html, they could type the name of the playlist and click create button. I want the owner field of the playlist to be equal to the currently logged in user.

You help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your code

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False,default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def playlist_id(self):
        return self.id
```

When you make the foreign key owner unique, it means that one user can have only one playlist. When you try to add another playlist for the same user your get this error

> UNIQUE constraint failed: music_playlist.owner_id

If you want one user to have only one playlist, use [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)